# Text remains hidden on hover in css?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to get a text to appear when you hover over the parent container (while the parent container gets opacity 0.5), but for some reason, it won't appear. I've tried three or four different methods, but it won't appear no matter what :((

Below is my current code.

```css
.project{
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.project:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.view-project{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s, visibility 0.2s;
}
.project:hover .view-project{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!--Parent class-->
<div class="project">
    <div class="project-text">
         <!--other things in here-->
         <!--This is the text I want hidden and then to appear upon hover-->
         <h2 class="view-project">View Project</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the actual code that will be children to the parent class `project` so that we can see how your `:hover` is currently working?

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be working accordingly. I went ahead and added `font-weight: bold;` to make sure I could see the hover content come through. Also, I noted out the opacity transition on hover so that it didn't have any odd effects when double-checking.

```css
.project{
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 50vw;
}
.project:hover{
    /* opacity: 0.5; */
}
.view-project{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s, visibility 0.2s;
}
.project:hover .view-project{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!--Parent class-->
<div class="project">
    <div class="project-text">
         <!--other things in here-->
         <p>other things in here</p>
         <!--This is the text I want hidden and then to appear upon hover-->
         <h2 class="view-project">View Project</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Furthermore, I changed your parent container `project` to have a `50vw / 50vh viewport` so that the actual word "View Project" was still clickable and didn't disappear when scrolling off the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `width` and `height` to `.project` class selector to shows the hover effect. That's it.

```css
.project{
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.project:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.view-project{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s, visibility 0.2s;
}
.project:hover .view-project{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!--Parent class-->
<div class="project">

    <div class="project-text">
         hover here
         <!--other things in here-->
         <!--This is the text I want hidden and then to appear upon hover-->
         <h2 class="view-project">View Project</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```